# how to delete id from MySQL Database using query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to delete Id on SQL not working i got  `string(87) "DELETE FROM wp_availability WHERE`id`IN (Array,Array,Array,Array)"`
get this kind value

```
if ( count( $remove ) > 0 ) {
        $removeSQL = "DELETE FROM " . $this->table . "  WHERE `id` IN (" . 
       implode( ",", $remove ) . ")";
       if ( $wpdb->query( $removeSQL ) ) {
      $saved = true;
   }
   }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Seems like your `$remove` variable is a collection of arrays rather than a collection of numbers. Use `var_dump($remove)` to see what it contains.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on `Vince0789`'s answer...

`$remove` looks to contain an array of arrays and not just an `id` string.

For example, `$remove` may be layed out as below;

```
[
    [ 
         'id' => 1,
         'content' => "Foo"
    ],
    [ 
         'id' => 2,
         'content' => "Bar"
    ],
]
```

What you will want to do is use `array_column()` on the `$remove` array to capture just the IDs from the array and then implode that new array and pass it to the query.

```
$to_remove = array_column($remove, 'id'); //assuming that id is the column you want
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php